# Migrating contacts to Office365

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, migration

i am doing a office 365 migration. So i need to do a migration of contacts from outlook 2016 or 13 to office 365.

After reading a few articles i am still not sure should it be exported as CSV or PST?

I am thinking it should be PST. Is that correct ?

Anyone have experience in this ?

Then after that i just import the PST to Office365 server?

Thank you

Comment: I would export to both formats just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Both PST and CSV file is ok. If you need to export email, contacts and calendar altogether, you can export to pst files. If you only need to migrate contacts, you may choose CSV file and follow the instructions in the following articles to export and import:

[Export contacts from Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-contacts-from-outlook-10f09abd-643c-4495-bb80-543714eca73f)

[Import contacts to Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-contacts-to-outlook-bb796340-b58a-46c1-90c7-b549b8f3c5f8)